# Conda finds conflicts with irrelevant packages

Tags: python, conda

After uninstall of Anaconda, and subsequent install in a different location (although, on the same PC), when I try this:

```
conda create --name xxx python==3.7
conda activate xxx
conda install -c conda-forge pandas opencv tesseract matplotlib
```

After hours of waiting, I see `conda` printing messages about how it found conflicts with libraries that have nothing to do with what it was asked to install, eg. Dask and so on.

By the way, Dask (likewise most other packages it finds conflicts with) was never installed on that PC, so, it's not a problem of stale cache.

Provided how idiotic this tool in general is... may I hope for a way to only install what it was told to install, and not check compatibility with things nobody asked it to install?

Comment: Solves fine (few seconds) specifying everything at outset (as one should): `conda create -n foo -c conda-forge python=3.7 pandas opencv tesseract matplotlib`. Note that Conda uses single `=`, unlike Pip.

Comment: Note that Conda's conflict reporting simply shows everything that has two or more constraints, whether or not they are actual conflicts. FWIW, [Mamba](https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba#readme) seems to be much better at this (as well as fast).

Comment: @merv On what operating system? It works fine on Linux, but, in general, conda is about 4 times slower to do everything on Windows, and, this particular example simply doesn't work on Windows. As for your second point... I just want to hit my head on the desk. How anyone could be so stupid as to think that this would be a good error reporting... it's the hands down worst dependency management I've seen in my life :(

Comment: @merv And, by the way, I sort of figured out why it didn't work on Windows... the thing is: Anaconda was installed with VSCode, which it suggested to install... and then VSCode on Windows defaults to using PowerShell. Now, `conda` environments simply don't work in this combination. I mean, you need to do `conda init powershell`, but this also doesn't work because then the shell will display an error at start, but won't actually do what it's supposed to. And conda doesn't report a failure, when it fails to activate an environment.

Comment: Long story short: I thought I was installing in a separate environment, but, actually, all installs went into the base environment. Also, uninstalling Anaconda doesn't remove the packages it installed. I mean the number of things it does wrong is hard to count... so, there were some leftover packages from previous install, which I didn't expect, and I wasn't installing in a separate environment, completely unaware of it. And, as a cherry on top, received a completely useless, but a very long and vague error message...